# Application of the Poisson distribution - flaws on glass.

Tags: probability

> Suppose a sheet of glass is manufactured to be $8\text{ft}\times10\text{ft}=80\text{ft}^2.$  The sheet contains $20$ flaws.  What is the probablity that a $4\text{ft}\times4\text{ft}=16\text{ft}^2$ contains exactly $3$ flaws.

First we compute $\lambda=20\text{ flaws}/80\text{ft}^2=.25\text{ flaws}/\text{ft}^2.$  Now we have $P(3)=\frac{4^3e^{-4}}{3!}=.049.$

I'm not sure if I approached this correctly.  I used $\mu=.25*16=4$.

Comment: Why do you compute $P(3)$ when you ask about $4$ flaws? I don't think the events are so rare that Poisson is appropriate, I would use binomial instead.

Comment: That was my mistake - 3 flaws.  It appears it would be rare from the calculation.  I thought we use Poissoin distributions when we are working with averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson distribution is appropriate when each event is very unlikely, but you have a lot of tries. Here each flaw is in your area with probability $1/5$, so a binomial distribution is appropriate.